# SQL - User input in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this. "Detail all films shown by the club between any two given dates, inputted by the user. For example a club member must be able to input a start date and an end date for the parameters for the query"

Now, how would I go about doing the user input? Only way I can think of would to be using php or something with a html form getting the values and then submitting them as variables in the query. However, that's not what is needed. So, how is this done so the query would ask for values? Or can't you?

My query so far looks like so.

```
SELECT film.title, film.desc, show.sdate, show.fdate
FROM film
INNER JOIN show
ON film.ID=show.filmID
WHERE sdate = '&userstart' AND fdate = '&userend'
```

How do I go about with the user input? Also, is the query correct? I have no way of testing, I only have a design not an implementation.

Thanks a lot

Edit: Using Windows system, MS SQL Server.

Comment: you cannot prompt from sql to user for inputs if you are using web applications. Your web application should handle all user inputs, check for sql injections and send values to sql query as parameter.

Comment: Depends on your SQL DBMS.  Some (like Oracle) have their own UI facilities, others (like MS SQL Server) do not and require you to add some client code such as c#, php, etc.

Comment: yes that is oracle forms but they are not truly sql prompting for user inputs, you still need to design UI for that.

Comment: @rs. Thanks, that was what I was thinking. So there is not a way to get user input from the query? Also, apart from that how does the query itself look?

Comment: @RBarryYoung It's not Oracle, it is MS SQL Server like you stated. Thanks, so it would need to be used with another language?

Comment: I think you need to clarify with your instructor as to what they're looking for.  It could be that they just want you to write a stored procedure that accepts two parameters.

Comment: @Jim If that's the case, what would I need to change to my query to make it like that? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code for a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeName(@UserStart DATETIME, @UserEnd DATETIME) 
AS BEGIN

SELECT somestuff
FROM sometable
WHERE somedate BETWEEN @UserStart AND @UserEnd

END
```

Comment: So, would I be able to use it like such.

`CREATE PROCEDURE BetweenDates(@UserStart DATETIME, @UserEnd DATETIME) 
AS BEGIN
SELECT film.title, film.desc, show.sdate, show.fdate
FROM film
INNER JOIN show
ON film.ID=show.filmID
WHERE sdate <= @UserStart AND fdate >= @UserEnd `

Comment: Like so? `CREATE PROCEDURE BetweenDates(@UserStart DATETIME, @UserEnd DATETIME) AS BEGIN SELECT film.title, film.desc, show.sdate, show.fdate FROM film INNER JOIN show ON film.ID=show.filmID WHERE sdate <= @UserStart AND fdate >= @UserEnd END` Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

@Kyle93 - 
Looking at your WHERE Clause:

**WHERE sdate = '&userstart' AND fdate = '&userend'**

This will only get you Films that had a sdate(Start Date?) equal to the date value entered.
You might want to use Greater than, Less Than operators....

Such as:

**WHERE sdate <= '&userend' AND  fdate >= '&userstart'**

(Note comparing sdate to UserEnd Date to make sure Film Showing started EARLIER than the UserEnd Date...etc)

This way - when a show starts OR ends within the date range - it will be selected.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about doing between.

Answer (score -2):

Are you familiar at all with LINQ? It's a way to make db calls from c#.

-- I would handle this with HTML as you thought, and use Javascript/Ajax to reference c# code that uses LINQ for db calls. Might be a bit complicated however, if you're not familiar with much of that. I can recommend good tutorials if interested tho.

Comment: Oh just saw your comments above. Bleh. Not enough info originally. I prefer Microsoft platforms :P

Comment: @jos No I am not. However, as I don't need to implement it you don't have to. However if you have some to hand I would not say no to learning a bit more about other ways to do things :)

Comment: It's very misleading to describe LINQ as "a way to make db calls from c#". [LINQ provides "general-purpose query facilities".](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) ['LINQ to SQL'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) translates between LINQ and SQL databases – maybe that's what you were thinking of or referring to as "LINQ". But LINQ isn't needed to access a DB with C# – using the .NET `System.Data` or `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace objects would probably be the simplest way to do so.