# How Do I Create A Procedure That Searches Data By Using a Value Typed By The User?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, select

For example: I want to create a procedure with a `Select` statement the searches the info of an animal, where the user types in any animal name and the procedure searches for it.

If the user types "Dog", I want to get every data of "Dog" in my table. Same with Cat, Bird, etc.

Comment: You either use a stored procedure with parameters or a parameterised query, but how you do this entirely depends on where you're getting the user input from - you don't really get user input from SQL...

Comment: Are users going to perform this search directly in SSMS or is this for an application that passes in a variable? You could create a stored procedure and but the select statement would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

use WHERE clause to filter the data in the table,

ex.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE animal = 'Dog'
```

Comment: I need that the Select Asks me What animal I want to search.

This works only if I'm searching a normal Select, and I'tll only give info if I modify the Select. I need a global in which the user only types the animal and it gives them all the info.

Comment: SQL-Server do not have UI facility unlike Oracle where you can use &input and it will ask you for the input. you may need to create stored procedure to call with parameter as your input. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974873/sql-user-input-in-query

Comment: Hmm... this changes many things haha. I checked the link and I'll work on another way based on some things I read there. Thank You!